# Does Visual Studio's built-in web server support HTTP PUT?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, http-put, webdev.webserver

Does the web server built into Visual Studio 2010 (and earlier, but 2010 in particular), `WebDev.WebServer.exe`, support the HTTP verb PUT? If so, does it support it by default or does it require configuration? If it requires configuration, please describe how to configure it.

Comment: Visual Studio's built-in web server is also known as the Visual Studio Development Server.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2010 at least, the Visual Studio Development Server web server *does* seem to support the HTTP PUT method.

I previously answered that it does not, but the URL for which I was submitting requests with the PUT method was incorrect. Once I corrected the URL the request was accepted without requiring any other changes to Visual Studio or the built-in web server settings.