# How to enable PUT and other HTTP methods in the Visual Studio Development Server web server?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, cassini, http-put

I'd like to debug a web service locally that accepts requests using the HTTP PUT method but when I try to do so the Visual Studio Development Server web server returns an error with the message "(405) Method Not Allowed".

See the related question [Does Visual Studio's built-in web server support HTTP PUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405137/does-visual-studios-built-in-web-server-support-http-put).

Answer (score 0):

My statement in the question description is incorrect. My 'trying' to debug a web service was ultimately incorrect – the URL of the request didn't match the URL of the web service. When I fixed the request URL I was able to successfully submit the request using the HTTP PUT method.

Short answer – nothing needs to be done to enable PUT (or other) HTTP methods in the Visual Studio Development Server web server.